# How to Resolve SOAP exception 'Unable to identify service '?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I am getting the following exception. I have attached a screenshot along. How to resolve the same? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This is to broad to answer. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The client is sending a request to the server and you should be able to see what parameters are being sent in the http headers in the request message.  SOAP indicates it is xml data being sent in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I cannot download sniffer or fiddler due to security reasons, just wanted to find if this error is generic and anybody else has faced the same.

Comment: From the exception , it seems that your address of client endpoint is not set correctly .Are you sure your client endpoint's address refers to a existing service? To specify your problem, you had better post your client side and server side configuration.